# Can Excel aggregate/combine x amount of datapoints and show an average instead of showing all datapoints?

Tags: excel, windows, charts, ms-office

I have a graph with data for each day. I would like to only show the average of the data per week on my graph.

[image: Part of the chart]

Here you can see a part of the chart. What I want is that these 21 (42) bars (days) shown in 3 (6) bars (weeks).

Can Excel do this without me having to manipulate the data and creating averages per week?

If Excel can't, what would be the most efficient way to create this dataset, if you know my data is organized following this structure (going until 31/12/2017).

[image: Data organization.]

I appreciate you reading my question and I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Plot a PivotChart with Average of for VALUES and ROWS (dates) grouped by Days and 7.